# Referenciar CSS na jsp através do$pagecontext.request.contextpath no tomcat8 não funciona

Tags: css, java-ee, jsp, tomcat

Estou usando o tomcat 8. Meus arquivos de css e js não carregam na jsp através do $pagecontext.request.contextpath  no tomcat8. Só consigo carregar o css se colocar o caminho absoluto a partir do diretorio webapp. Ex(paginas/css/estilo.css).

A estrutura do projeto é a seguinte:

src
   webapp
      paginas
         css
         js
**Obs:** Meus arquivos jsp estão na mesma hierarquia das pastas js e css.

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>Yellow Pages</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>paginas/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list> ...
```

O Head do jsp:

```
<link  type="text/css" href="${request.contextPath}css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link  type="text/css" href="${request.contextPath}css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda, obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A seguinte configuração de jsp no web.xml estava errada:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
"-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >
```

Após muito pesquisar, encontrei alguém com o mesmo problema neste [link](http://grokbase.com/t/tomcat/users/123bqbm3hj/pagecontext-request-contextpath-not-resolving), constatei que a versão especificada de JSP não suportava Expression Language.

Inseri a seguinte especificação mais atualizada e obtive sucesso:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0"
    >
```

Answer (score 3):

Tentou usar da seguinte maneira?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/estilo.css" type="text/css"/>
```

Se isso não funcionar tente colocar o valor de ${pageContext.request.contextPath} dentro de um input para saber qual é o valor que ele armazena:

```
<input value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}">
```

Comment: Após tentar, verifiquei que estava sendo renderizado como texto. Obrigado!